# Can't open 6 MB file in Paint, error says there is not enough RAM

Tags: windows-xp, memory, microsoft-paint

I have a JPG file of 6 MB. It can be opened by AI or Photoshop but when I try to open it with Paint, an error message is saying that there is not enough RAM or resources to open the file.

I wonder what the problem is and how to fix it, it doesn't seem to be a real RAM problem to me because the file can be opened in AI or other program, but just not by Paint.

Comment: Which OS?  Basically determines which version of paint you are trying.

Comment: @hydroparadise its window xp

Comment: Doh!  Well theres a similar question about Paint.Net that might give some insight to your issue.  http://superuser.com/questions/204317/is-there-a-file-size-limit-in-paint-net

Comment: Attach the file to your question (if it's not something private, offensive or inappropriate) so that others can try it.

Answer (score 2):

I can verify this issue, with an image I created locally, 16k pixels x 9k pixels, 600 pixels per inch, saved to a 7.1mb jpg file (using photoshop).  There are also a few posts out on the net regarding similar issues where people have created super large images in paint, and then have not been able to save them.  This isn't the same as the paint.net issue, since it deals with the local executable mspaint.exe.

It is apparently a bug/coded limitation within the software, as mspaint.exe is in no way a professional tool and was never designed to work with images of this size.  Apparently, the fix is... if you need to work with images this big, stick to better tools like Photoshop, Gimp, AI, etc.